# Warning: fopen failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable in /XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/search.php

Tags: php, http, fopen

I am trying to fetch search results from pubmed.

```
$query=(BRCA1[tiab]) OR (Breast cancer 1 gene[tiab])AND (Cancer[tiab])
$esearch = 'http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=$query&retmax=10&usehistory=y';
$handle = fopen($esearch, "r");
$rettype = "abstract"; //retreives abstract of the record, rather than full record
$retmode = "xml";
```

I get this HTTP Access Failure error.

**Error:**

> Warning: fopen([http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=(BRCA1[tiab])](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=%28BRCA1%5btiab%5d%29) OR (Breast cancer 1 gene[tiab]) AND (Cancer[tiab])&retmax=10&usehistory=y): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/search.php on line 60

When I directly paste the url, [http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=(BRCA1[tiab])](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=%28BRCA1%5btiab%5d%29) OR (Breast cancer 1 gene[tiab]) AND (Cancer[tiab])&retmax=10&usehistory=y I get search results in the page but not when accessing through the php script.

Comment: Try `file_get_contents` for remore URLs

Comment: You have a syntax error on the first line

Comment: Also single quotes don't do what you think they do. Reading material http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: file_get_contents gives the same error @entiendoNull

Comment: The quotes didnt make a difference here @PeeHaa

Comment: The first line needs a semi colon. I missed it here but it is present in the original code @PeeHaa

Comment: You have a few issues: syntax errors, no url encoding, concatenation errors. See my answer below.

Comment: Yeah it just needs a semicolon.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here. First, you have a syntax error on the first line, where you have plain text without quotes. We can fix that by replacing this line:

```
$query=(BRCA1[tiab]) OR (Breast cancer 1 gene[tiab])AND (Cancer[tiab])
```

with this line:

```
$query = "(BRCA1[tiab]) OR (Breast cancer 1 gene[tiab])AND (Cancer[tiab])";
```

This now fixes that syntax error.

Secondly, you have a silent string concat error in your second line. If you want to concatenate variables inline (without using the `.` operator) you have to use double quotes, not single quotes. Let's fix that by replacing this line:

```
$esearch = 'http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=$query&retmax=10&usehistory=y';
```

with this line:

```
$esearch = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=$query&retmax=10&usehistory=y";
```

Lastly, you're not urlencoding the query, thus you're getting spaces in your URL that are not encoded and are messing up the URL for fopen. Let's wrap the query string in `urlencode()`:

```
$query = urlencode("(BRCA1[tiab]) OR (Breast cancer 1 gene[tiab])AND (Cancer[tiab])");
$esearch = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=$query&retmax=10&usehistory=y"; 
$handle = fopen($esearch, "r"); 
$rettype = "abstract"; //retreives abstract of the record, rather than full record 
$retmode = "xml";
```

I tested this code on CLI and it seems to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and guiding it patiently. It works now.

Comment: @jsanc623 it throw same error to me Im using POST request. Please help me sir. Thanks